# C# Linq Expression Tree ( searching in a lists using exists method)

Tags: c#, linq, tree, expression

I would like to form a Linq expression tree like

```
listInstance.Exists(c=>c.Age=-40)
```

I have written the code, but when calling the `Expression.Call` method, it's throwing an error.

The code I've written is here,

```cs
private static string GetExprString<T>(List<Student> listInstance,int valueExpr){

    var methodInfo = typeof(List<Student>).GetMethod("Exists",new Type[] { typeof(Predicate<Student>)});            

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "c");
    var masterProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(Student).GetProperty("Age"));
    var slInstance = Expression.Constant(sList);

    var expr = Expression.Equal(masterProperty, Expression.Constant(valueExpr));
    e1 = Expression.Lambda(expr, new ParameterExpression[] {parameter });
    var left = Expression.Call(slInstance, methodInfo, e1);

    return string.empty;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to create a new Extension method with the name of Exists?

Comment: No I'm trying to use the Exists method in the List class using Expression tree

Comment: @KannanSrinivasan: Why though? What are you trying to accomplish here that cannot be done with existing methods? Why not use the existing `.Exists()`, or even a simple LINQ `.Any()` ?

Comment: Why are you manually building the `Expression` rather than just passing a lambda? Is there a particular reason you're using this approach? As you're discovering, it's significantly more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to build a business rule engine which will build rules dynamically and validate the object

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you want to use an expression tree rather than just call passing a lambda to `Exists`, but as you're asking then you can do this without having to build up the `Expression` tree yourself by letting the compiler do the heavy lifting for you:

```
static LambdaExpression MakeExistsExpression(int age)
{
    Expression<Func<List<Student>, bool>> func= (listInstance) => listInstance.Exists(c => c.Age == age);
    return (LambdaExpression)func;
}
```

Now you can say:

```
var func = MakeExistsExpression(40);
var lambda = (Func<List<Student>,bool>)func.Compile();
bool found = lambda(students);
```

Where `students` is your list of students that you've sourced from somewhere.

Comment: Exactly what I was just typing.  I see so many people needlessly trying to manually make expression trees, when they could just use the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

seems like you missed an equal sign in your expression:

```
listInstance.Exists(c=>c.Age=40)
```

change it to:

```
listInstance.Exists(c => c.Age == 40)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I included the c=>c.Age==40 , but still Expression.Call is throwing error         var e1 = Expression.Lambda(expr, new ParameterExpression[] {parameter });
            var left = Expression.Call(slInstance, methodInfo, e1);

Comment: You've pointed at a flaw in the question's code, but this does not answer the question that is asked.